# How to render a view with specific text?

Tags: zend-framework, view, php

**I have a class like this:**

```
class myData {
  function render(){
    $str = 'This is string.';
    // have to code here
  }
}
```

**and a myview.phtml file:**

```
<div id='someid'></div>
```

**Q: Now I want to do something like this in another phtml file:**

```
<?php
$obj = new myData ();
echo $obj->render(); // it should be <div id='someid'>This is string.</div>
?>
```

So how can I change my **render** function in **myData** class that it should get **myview.phtml** and place string between **DIV tag**(`<div id='someid'></div>`) and print.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean `</div>` instead of `<dev>` (note the `e` and the lack of a closing tag)? It appears in several spots; otherwise, I would assume it was a typo.

Comment: @ClosureCowboy: Sorry, That was typo.. Question edited..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution could be to use [Partial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.partial) view helper. This helper can be used to " render a specified template within its own variable scope".

Specifically in *myview.phtml* you can add the following:

```
  <div id='someid'><?php echo $this->myText; ?></div>
```

Then, in the *another phtml* you could have:

```
<?php
$obj = new myData ();
echo $this->partial('path/to/myview.phtml',array('myText' => $obj->render()));
?>
```

Comment: I think I can use `return $this->partial('path/to/myview.phtml',array('myText' => $str));` in **render** function of **myData** class. Is it good practice ?

Comment: @Awan. Difficult to anwser to this, as I don't know what myData class is. Does it represent your models, or is it more like view helpers to be used only in the views, or like zend_form that have mixture of logic and presentation (through decorators). Generally, you should not mix presentation of your data (i.e. html) with your models or logic. You use MVC pattern to separate this stuff, not to mix it. But it's up to your requirements. Off course, this general rule of MVC cannot be applied to every single case.

Comment: @Marcin: **myData** class is used to display/represent data on webpage. It is not Model or Form. I want to create a class which will provide me data in HTML table format and I will render it in view.

Comment: @Awan. So it is more as a view helper. Thus, if you would like to do it the Zend way, I would recommend to consider creating a custom view helper. But using myData in the way you do should also be OK, as it's main task is to render data. So, if you want to use partial helper in the myData class, it should be able to access the current view. You could pass the current view object through your constructor in the view,e.g. new myData($this). This should allow you to easily access all view helpers (I hope, as I never tried that).

Comment: Now I am doing something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982769/access-views-in-models-controllers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

http://webgen.hu/class.html.txt

http://webgen.hu/class.html.php

Comment: this was made only for fun in spare time. use as you wish if you see it usefull. btw its a bit buggy...