# Access views in Models/Controllers

Tags: php, zend-framework, view, render

**I have a class MyData.php like this:**

```
class myData {
  function render() {
    $view = new Zend_View();
    $view->str = 'This is string.';
    echo $view->render('myview.phtml');
  }
}
```

**and a myview.phtml file:**

```
<div id='someid'><?= $this->str ?></div>
```

In another view I am doing something like this:

```
<?php
    $obj = new myData ();
    $obj->render(); // it should be <div id='someid'>This is string.</div>
?>
```

It is giving me following exception:

```
Message: no view script directory set; unable to determine location for view script
```

**MyData.php** and **myview.phtml** are in same directory.

Comment: @prodigitalson: Can you provide an example that fit in my above requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it like this:

I changed my **myview.phtml** to **myview.php**

`<div id='someid'><?= $this->str ?></div>`

In myData class render function:

```
class myData {
  function render() {
    $view = new Zend_View();
    $view->setScriptPath( "/Directory/Path/For/myview/php/file" );
    $view->str = 'This is string.';
    echo $view->render('myview.php');
  }
}
```

And all things are working as I asked in question. I was missing `$view->setScriptPath($path);` in my code.

**Help:**

- http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.scripts.html
- http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=69&t=3966#p15370
- http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-2353

Comment: This would also work in cases where you use Zend Framework to run cronjobs with stripped down bootstrap.

Answer (score 5):

You are creating a new Zend_View instance. You should not do this. To get the existing view instance you could do as follows:

```
$view = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap')->getResource('view');
```

Also, I think that the view script path should be relative to `APPLICATION_PATH/views/scripts` folder.

Answer (score 2):

If you are usin the full MVC stack its youre better off just creating a view helper for this type of thing... or simply passing the using the Partial view helper and passing your object to it.

For example with the exisiting Zend_View_Helper_Partial....

in your controller create the myData object and assign it to the view:

```
public function indexAction()
{
   $this->view->mydata = new MyData();
}
```

in the view for the action:

```
echo $this->partial('myview.phtml', array('obj' => $this->mydata));
```

Then in your `myview.phtml` you can do:

```
<div><?php echo $this->obj->somevar ?></div>
```

For your example it looks like you dont even need the myData object at all you can just assign the `str` variable to the view and pass it along to the partial instead of creating an object.

You should read the [`Zend_View` docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.html)...