# How can i make my own view helpers such as $this->partial or $this->render?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Like we can do $this->partial(); or $this->render() with Zend Framework. How can i make my own $this->myOwnStuff(); ?

```
Example:
Before:
<tr>
 <td>label</td>
 <td>value1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>label2</td>
 <td>value2</td>
</tr>

After:
$this->tr(
  array(
    "label"=>"value1", "value"=> "value1"
    "label"=>"value2", "value"=> "value2"
  )
);
```

Comment: read this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982769/access-views-in-models-controllers

Comment: @NAVEED: But i need to apply once, and it can be used in all controller and views. Where the example is only used when needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy. If you want to create a helper, just create a new helper class and plot it in `/application/views/helpers`. Of if you're structuring it so that you have your own library putting it in `library/My_Library/View/Helper` will also work.

Make sure to extend from the base helper abstract. Something along the lines of

```
class My_View_Helper_Stuff extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract {
}
```

Here's an article that goes into greater detail about the matter : http://devzone.zend.com/article/3412